# Android Lollipop not able to identify difference between setOnPreferenceChangeListener and setOnPreferenceClickListener

Tags: android

`Android Lollipop` not able to identify difference between `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` and `setOnPreferenceClickListener` and calls both callbacks `onPreferenceChange` and `onPreferenceClick` irrespective of whether we change the preference or click the preference.

I am trying this for `SwitchPreference` in `PreferenceFragment` sub class.
Thanks in advance for any useful help.

Comment: Why you not using one of them if you get same callback ?

Comment: I need to perform two different functionality on each call back..
So I need to get it recognized weather preference is changed or clicked.
Hope you understand.